# how can i Get rating Factory in magento 2 ?

Tags: magento2

I need to get rating factory i try following both way but i show white page any one know what i doing wrong.
First Using Objectmanager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$ratingObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Rating');
print_r($ratingObj);
exit;
```

Second way using construct in my block for example

```
namespace Companyname\Modulename\Block;

class Customreview extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
  protected $_ratingFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Review\Model\RatingFactory $ratingFactory, 
        array $data = []
    ){
       $this->_ratingFactory = $ratingFactory; 
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getRatings()
    {
       return $this->_ratingFactory->create()->getResourceCollection()->addEntityFilter(
            'product'
        )->setPositionOrder()->addRatingPerStoreName(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->setStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->setActiveFilter(
            true
        )->load()->addOptionToItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: You will be getting a white page because you are printing out the object and the objects are very large. Try print_r(get_class($ratingObj));

Comment: i try get class but showing blank page.

Comment: In what context are you running your first piece of code. I have just tried it in a sample file and it works just fine suggesting that you have another issue elsewhere.

Comment: Have you try second code pls i need available rating in my custom module.

Comment: No. I would first suggest you look in your magento logs and then your apache error logs for the real issue.

Comment: The code snippets look good. Are you sure that your first snippet is executed? Can you debug it or just print out some text before this code.
Regarding second snippet, try to check, that factory \Magento\Review\Model\RatingFactory has been generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in printing a long object. I have tried the second way and write `<?php print_r($block->getRatings()->getData()); ?>`

I forgot to add `getData()` on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    ...
}

public function getRatingSummary()
{
    ...
    $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();

    return $ratingSummary;
}
```